# Compile command not running in staging environment

Tags: configuration, php-7, command-line, mamp, centos

When I run `$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile` command on local machine, it recompiles dependencies right away. When I do the same on staging server, it displays a message:

```
DI configuration must be cleared before running compiler. Please delete '/var/www/html/staging/var/di'.
```

Of course, when I delete var/di, it works. But my question is, why it does not require that directory to be deleted when running on local?

Local runs MAMP with php7.0.0.
Staging runs centos7 with php7.0.7, php-fpm and SElinux.

What difference between these two environments could lead to different command behavior?

Comment: Please delete '/var/www/html/staging/var/di'. have you deleted it ?

Comment: Yes I have and it worked. But I'm not asking how to make it work. I edited my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/var/di` is only used in production mode. If it exists it needs to be deleted before you can run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`. I am assuming your local site is in developer mode and hence does not have this folder.

Comment: They both run in developer mode. At least console says so. But you are right - local does not have di folder and staging does.

Comment: Ha! I just re-set the mode on staging to developer and ran compile command. It worked now. I guess the `deploy:mode:show` command was outputting wrong mode, not the one that application was actually in.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the directory, not only the files inside var/di. Took me a while to figure that out :-)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm asking about. I edited my question for more clarity.